# Viewer Connection to hypervisor host got refused

Tags: linux, kvm

I used the inbuilt VNC-Viewer in the virt-manager to see the VM desktops.
But now when I click the Play button in the VM Window to see the desktop
of the VM named `server1.example.com`, I get an error message like below:

```
Error : Viewer Connection to hypervisor host got refused
or disconnected!
```

Below is my configuration from `/etc/libvirt/qemu/server1.example.com`

```
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made      
using: virsh edit server1.example.com or other application using the 
libvirt API.
-->

<domain type='kvm'>
<name>server1.example.com</name>
<uuid>ca13796e-5917-bff4-b4ca-1203f660cbb2</uuid>
<memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
<currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
<vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>
<os>
<type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.4.0'>hvm</type>
<boot dev='hd'/>
</os>
<features>
<acpi/>
<apic/>
<pae/>
</features>
<clock offset='utc'/>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>restart</on_crash>
<devices>
<emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/server1.example.com.img'/>
  <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
  <readonly/>
  <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<controller type='usb' index='0'>
</controller>
<controller type='ide' index='0'>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01'     
function='0x1'/>
</controller>
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:e1:ba:1e'/>
  <source network='default'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03'    
  function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<serial type='pty'>
  <target port='0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty'>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
</console>
<input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
<graphics type='vnc' port='5901' autoport='no' listen='127.0.0.1'>
  <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
</graphics>
```

I had a bad feeling about my iptables rules, so I have decided to add
/etc/sysconfig/iptables file. Please see below.

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 23 -j  ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5903 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5904 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5901 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5902 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5903 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5904 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i wlan0 -o vibr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -i vibr0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Below are the virtualization packages on my system :

```
libvirt.x86_64           0.10.2-18.el6                     @localrepo
libvirt-client.x86_64    0.10.2-18.el6                     @localrepo
libvirt-python.x86_64    0.10.2-18.el6                     @localrepo
python-virtinst.noarch   0.600.0-15.el6                    @localrepo
virt-manager.x86_64      0.9.0-18.el6                      @localrepo
virt-what.x86_64         1.11-1.2.el6                      @base/6
```

I have tried viewing the VM desktop using the tiger-vnc
and that was a success.
Can somebody suggest a method to resolve this issue?

**Part added after the edit** :
Surpisingly the virt-viewer command works fine, Also the 
remote-desktop-viewer (vinagre) does the job.

```
[ssam@centos ~]$ virt-viewer --debug -c qemu:///system 2
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Insert window 0 0x1a25890
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: fullscreen display 0: 0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: fullscreen display 0: 0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Opening connection to libvirt with URI 
   qemu:///system
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Add handle 7 1 0x1a8d5c0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: notebook show status 0x1a24190
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: notebook show status 0x1a24190
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Guest 2 is running, determining display
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Set connect info: (null),(null),(null),-1,
   (null),(null),(null),0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Guest 2 has a vnc display
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Guest graphics address is 127.0.0.1:5901
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Set connect info: localhost,127.0.0.1,5901,-1,
   (null),(null),(null),0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Error operation virDomainOpenGraphics 
    forbidden for read only access
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: After open connection callback fd=-1
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Opening direct TCP connection to display at 
   127.0.0.1:5901:-1
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: notebook show status 0x1a24190
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Add timeout 0x1a9abf0 -1 0x3ee80aa2b0 
   0x1a8d900 1
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: notebook show status 0x1a24190
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: notebook show display 0x1a24190
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Display size request 100x100 (desktop 100x100)
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Allocated 400x375
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Child allocate 375x375
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: desktop resize 1024x768
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Preparing main window resize
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Decided todo 1024x768 (desktop is 1024x768,
   fullscreen is 1280x800
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Display size request 1024x768 (desktop 
   1024x768)
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Allocated 1024x768
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Child allocate 1024x768
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Display size request 50x50 (desktop 1024x768)
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Allocated 1024x768
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Child allocate 1024x768
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Dispatch handler 7 1 0x1a8d5c0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Dispatch handler 7 2 0x1a8d5c0
** (virt-viewer:7930): DEBUG: Dispatch handler 7 1 0x1a8d5c0
```

Comment: What distro are you on? There's a bug regarding something similar for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/837275, though your output looks like `yum`.

Comment: @slm: I am on `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`

Comment: Found this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767170, also what version of virt-manager and libvirt are you using?

Comment: `virt-manager.x86_64 - 0.9.0-18.el6`
`libvirt.x86_64     - 0.10.2-18.el6`

Comment: Do you have access to another virt-manager that you could use to connect to this server libvirt? Trying to eliminate either virt-manager or libvirt as the issue.

Comment: Let me downgrade the versions and try once more. I'll be back soon

Comment: @slm No luck with virt-manager-.10 as well..

Comment: Try `virt-manager --debug`. Also to isolate the issue further, can you just run `virt-viewer` from the command line directly? It also has switches `--verbose` and `--debug`.

Comment: @slm : I also encountered a Selinux Policy Violation
`SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm from write access on the file /var/lib/libvirt/images/server1.example.com.img.
Source Context                unconfined_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c241,c526
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:virt_image_t:s0:c241,c526`
Then had a look at the [libvirt documentation](http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html) and changed the context of the storage media from virt_image_t to svirt_image_t. Didn't add a custom policy though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my centos machine, reverting `127.0.0.1` entry in `/etc/hosts` file to `localhost` fixed this problem. I found this solution is some other place.   I thought to share with you all about this.

Comment: @sivakumara This solved the issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution but more a confirmation of the problem. While googliing for this particular issue I came across the following references to it:

- [[libvirt-users] Debugging TLS connection between virt-viewer and libvirt running on separate hosts](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2013-March/msg00012.html)
- [Virtual Machine Viewer gives "Error: viewer connection to hypervisor host got refuse or disconnected!"](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/143293)
- [Bug#708209: virt-manager: unable to connect viewer](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-708209-virt-manager-unable-connect-viewer-help-211337282.html)
- [Debian Bug report logs - #708209 virt-manager: unable to connect viewer (duplicate of above)](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=708209)

I would also suggest filing a bug on the [virt-manager's project page](http://virt-manager.org/bugs/). The direct links:

*Viewing*

- [Open virt-manager bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?product=Virtualization%20Tools&classification=Community&component=virt-manager&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED)
- [Open virt-viewer bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?product=Virtualization%20Tools&classification=Community&component=virt-viewer&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED)

*Reporting*

- [File new virt-manager bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Virtualization%20Tools&component=virt-manager)
- [File new virt-viewer bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Virtualization%20Tools&component=virt-viewer)

I looked through the database for your error message but did not see anything.

Comment: If you want to track this issue click [here](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6678)

Answer (score 0):

Add `localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` file after machine's domain name and hostname. 
e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 server1.example.com server1 localhost
```

Worked for me !!!!!
I hope it worked for all !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, linux iptables is blocking the input connection. Hence you are not able connect the kvm guest console.

So better to understand this problem, initially try to flush your iptables rules then try the same if your console connected, the problem is firewall.

To flush the iptables:

```
iptables -F
```

To view the rules:

```
iptables -L
```

To solve the problem, you need to disable the iptables INPUT rule rejection.

Comment: thanks pal, can't confirm this though.. because i've had my centos upgraded long ago ;)